# add alias to webpack config by npm script?

Tags: react-native, npm, webpack, node-modules, react-native-web

I have to put in `node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.dev.js`
the following alias manually:

```
react-native-linear-gradient': 'react-native-web-linear-gradient',
```

Is there any way I can have a command `package.json` in `"scripts"` section to add this alias when I run it?

Comment: You can do that, but it would be interesting to know *why* you would want to do something like that. Modifying source code automatically before running it seems like a clunky workaround for something that could be achieved much more elegantly

Comment: @PatrickHund I use React Native Web so when I run the code on web it import from web js instead of Mobile target js

Comment: Also I don't want to eject the react app or using a plugin like

Comment: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-react-native-web/src/index.js